# android There are no error in project script but but no execute

Tags: java, android

Hello I am fresher in android. but execute some project in eclipse. But today when I open eclipse then my old (Which I already run one day before) show error in  left side panel of eclipse screen. I thoroughly checked all script but there are no error. but when I execute message shown

YOUR PROJECT CONTAIN ERROR(S), PLEASE FIX THEM BEFORE RUNNING YOUR APPLICATION.

Here is screen shoot of eclipse screen where error displayed

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Try to clean your project

Comment: have you try to find exact error in problem window?

Comment: can you please send your project in my mail then i'll try to solve your problem ?

Comment: clean and build,save all...restarting eclipse may  also help

Answer (score 0):

*To check errors:-*

Right Click on your project then go for `Android Tools` then `Run Lint`.
Check your error in the Lint error checking window which will come below.

This error might be due to `Missing Translation`.

Try this:-

Go to **Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking**

Find there `Missing Translation` and change its `Severity` to `Warning`.
 Press *Apply* and then *OK*.